# How can I turn pandas dataframe into an ordered list with many to one relationship?

Tags: python, list, pandas, many-to-one

I currently have a pandas dataframe where there are many answers joined on a single question, so I am trying to turn it into a list so I can do cosine similarity.

Currently I have the dataframe, where the questions are joined by the answers through the parent_id = q_id, as shown in the picture:

[many answers to one question dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8tjK5.jpg)

```
print (df)
   q_id      q_body  parent_id    a_body
0     1  question 1          1  answer 1
1     1  question 1          1  answer 2
2     1  question 1          1  answer 3
3     2  question 2          2  answer 1
4     2  question 2          2  answer 2
```

and the product I am looking for is:

("question 1", "answer 1", "answer 2", "answer 3")

("question 2", "answer 1", "answer 2")

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with `apply`:

```
#output is tuple with question value
df = df.groupby('q_body')['a_body'].apply(lambda x: tuple([x.name] + list(x)))
print (df)
q_body
question 1    (question 1, answer 1, answer 2, answer 3)
question 2              (question 2, answer 1, answer 2)
Name: a_body, dtype: object

#output is list with question value
df = df.groupby('q_body')['a_body'].apply(lambda x: [x.name] + list(x))
print (df)
q_body
question 1    [question 1, answer 1, answer 2, answer 3]
question 2              [question 2, answer 1, answer 2]
Name: a_body, dtype: object
```

```
#output is list without question value
df = df.groupby('q_body')['a_body'].apply(list)
print (df)
q_body
question 1    [answer 1, answer 2, answer 3]
question 2              [answer 1, answer 2]
Name: a_body, dtype: object

#grouping by parent_id without question value
df = df.groupby('parent_id')['a_body'].apply(list)
print (df)
parent_id
1    [answer 1, answer 2, answer 3]
2              [answer 1, answer 2]
Name: a_body, dtype: object

#output is string, values are concanecated by ,
df = df.groupby('parent_id')['a_body'].apply(', '.join)
print (df)
parent_id
1    answer 1, answer 2, answer 3
2              answer 1, answer 2
Name: a_body, dtype: object
```

But if need output as list add [`tolist`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.tolist.html):

```
L = df.groupby('q_body')['a_body'].apply(lambda x: tuple([x.name] + list(x))).tolist()
print (L)
[('question 1', 'answer 1', 'answer 2', 'answer 3'), ('question 2', 'answer 1', 'answer 2')]
```

Comment: Thank you jezrael, will be using lambda alot more now.

Comment: Glad can help you. Nice day.

Answer (score 2):

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
        ['question 1', 'answer 1'],
        ['question 1', 'answer 2'],
        ['question 1', 'answer 3'],
        ['question 2', 'answer 1'],
        ['question 2', 'answer 2'],
    ], columns=['q_body', 'a_body'])

print(df)

       q_body    a_body
0  question 1  answer 1
1  question 1  answer 2
2  question 1  answer 3
3  question 2  answer 1
4  question 2  answer 2
```

---

## `apply(list)`

```
df.groupby('q_body').a_body.apply(list)

q_body
question 1    [answer 1, answer 2, answer 3]
question 2              [answer 1, answer 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

See if it helps you

```
result = df.groupby('q_id').agg({'q_body': lambda x: x.iloc[0], 'a_body': lambda x: ', '.join(x)})
result['output'] = result.q_body + ', ' + result.a_body
```

This will create a new column **output** with the desired result.